# Swift Generics and Protocols

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Given the below, this will throw a compile time error about the protocol not being able to adhere to itself and only struct/enum can adhere to the protocol. This seems to defeat the purpose of being able to use protocols in generics. I'm trying to understand why this doesn't work, but if I remove the generic and just put the protocol where 'Z' is everything is fine. It seems antithetical to what protocols and generics should be allowed for.

**Edit for question clarity: I need to take a type of Any that can be cast to a dictionary of `[String:MyProtocol]` and pass it into the method `printEm`. `printEm` must use the generic as it will be instantiating instances of the class `Z`.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  init()
  var whoAmI:String { get }
}

func genericPassing(unknownThing:Any) {
  let knownThing = unknownThing as? [String:MyProtocol]
  if(knownThing != nil){
    self.printEm(knownThing)
  }
}

func printEm<Z:MyProtocol>(theThings:[String:Z]) {
  let zCollection:[Z] = []
  for thing in theThings {
    print(thing.whoAmI)
    zCollection.append(Z())
  }
}
```

**Edited printEm to illustrate why generic is needed.

** Edit for more complex code. The two primary requirements are the use of a generic to call Z() and the ability to take an Any and somehow type check it and/or cast it so that it can be used in a genericized method.

```
private func mergeUpdates<Z:RemoteDataSyncable>(source:inout Z, updates:[WritableKeyPath<Z, Any>:Any]) throws {
        for key in updates.keys {
            let value = updates[key]!
            let valueDict = value as? [String:[WritableKeyPath<RemoteDataSyncable, Any>:Any]]
            if(valueDict != nil) {
                var currentValueArray = source[keyPath: key] as? [RemoteDataSyncable]
                if(currentValueArray != nil) {
                    self.mergeUpdates(source: &currentValueArray!, updates: valueDict!)
                }
                else {
                    throw SyncError.TypeError
                }
            }
            else {
                source[keyPath: key] = value
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func mergeUpdates<Z:RemoteDataSyncable>(source:inout [Z], updates:[String:[WritableKeyPath<Z,Any>:Any]]) {
        for key in updates.keys {
            var currentObject = source.first { syncable -> Bool in
                return syncable.identifier == key
            }
            if(currentObject != nil) {
                try! self.mergeUpdates(source: &currentObject!, updates: updates[key]!)
            }
            else {
                var newSyncable = Z()
                try! self.mergeUpdates(source: &newSyncable, updates: updates[key]!)
                source.append(newSyncable)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: (1) What are you trying to do? (2) What's the question?

Comment: @matt
I need those two methods above not to throw a compile error. More specifically, I need to be able to take a dictionary that has a protocol as it's generic and pass it into a genericized method. So, I need to be able to pass [String:MyProtocol] into func printEm<Z:MyProtocol>(theThigns; [String:Z]) such that I can do theThings["key"].whoAmI as well as Z(). Beyond that, I'd like to understand why the current implementation does not work, as it seems to be the very essence of what generics and protocols should be able to handle and does in many other languages.

Comment: As the error says, protocols do not conform to themselves, but you don't need them to. Your generic isn't doing anyting. Get rid of it. This should be `func printEm(theThings: [String: MyProtocol])`.

Comment: "pass [String:MyProtocol] into func printEm<Z:MyProtocol>(theThigns; [String:Z])" - no, that's not what Z means there. `Z:MyProtocol` means "a MyProtocol adopter". You would pass `[String:What]` where What conforms to MyProtocol.

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that, but that won't work. I'll adjust above to show why that won't work in my specific case. Is there possibly a way to get the generic used for `uknownThings` and pass that in as `Z`?

Comment: Edited above to show why I am unable to use a non-generic method

Comment: So what do you expect your new code to do? What class would it initialize inside the method when the dictionary you pass in has `MyProtocol` as the type of its value?

Comment: My code need is pretty complex so I've boiled it down above into a more digestable format. I'm working with key, value pairs where the key is a key path. This is merging into a nested list of keypath/value pairs that are used to keep an update queue. This is then used to set an object, Z, on update. To include all that KeyPath stuff would distract from the actual issue, which is taking that Any and somehow getting it into `printEm` so that I can both use .whoAmI and Z(). The class it initializes should not matter except that it conforms to MyProtocol and thus has a required initializer.

Comment: `WritableKeyPath<Z,Any>` means that the property must be of type `Any`. Is that really what you mean? That's doesn't feel very useful. This doesn't look like a very fruitful approach to whatever you're trying to do. I would generally recommend closures rather than complex keypath approaches.

Comment: Please quote the exact error you're getting in the question.

Comment: This may be a misunderstanding of keypaths. I haven't gotten that deep yet. I need to solve this first problem first. That's why I didn't want to include the KeyPaths in the original question, since it seemed like it might distract from the actual issue. For now, let's just think of them as [Z:Any] for the sake of argument. Eventually, they would be used to do object[keyPath: key] = value, but that isn't what's causing the current problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example of why protocols do not conform to themselves. In your code `Z` is `MyProtocol`, so `Z()` is `MyProtocol()`. How would that work? What type is it? How big is it? You then can't put them into a `[Z]`, since they might be different types.

You mean to pass arbitrary MyProtocols and call `init` on the type of each element:

```
func printEm(theThings:[String: MyProtocol]) {
    var zCollection:[MyProtocol] = []
    for thing in theThings.values {
        print(thing.whoAmI)
        zCollection.append(type(of: thing).init())
    }
}
```

---

When I suggested using closures, this is the kind of thing I mean. This Updater can accept arbitrary ReferenceWritableKeyPaths, and when you pass it Any update value, it'll assign it to every key path that can accept it. That's kind of useless, but shows the technique. (Keep in mind that the updater is retaining the object, so that may be a problem that you need to address.)

```
class Updater {
    private(set) var updaters: [(Any) -> ()] = []

    func add<Root, Value>(keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Root, Value>, on root: Root) {
        updaters.append { value in
            if let value = value as? Value {
                root[keyPath: keyPath] = value
            }
        }
    }

    func updateAll(with value: Any) {
        for updater in updaters {
            updater(value)
        }
    }
}

class Client {
    var updateMe: Int = 0
}

let client = Client()

let updater = Updater()
updater.add(keyPath: \.updateMe, on: client)

updater.updateAll(with: 3)

client.updateMe // 3
```

The key lesson in this code is that the generic types on the `add` are erased (hidden) by the `(Any) -> ()` closure at compile-time. And the runtime `as?` check is done inside that closure, where the types are all known.

Comment: Man I got really excited about this one, but it doesn't match my use case unfortunately. I may have boiled too much of the complexity out of my example. I've went ahead and added my more complex example for why the above won't solve my issue. I don't have an instance of "thing" so I need to call Z() because I don't have a current instance to pull that typing out of.

Comment: Also, good explanation on why the error is the way it is. I understand that much better now. I'm beginning to wonder if it is possible to extract the typing from the Any and then use that to clarify what Z is when calling the method.

Comment: Generics are completely evaluated at compile-time. I think you're trying to then evaluate them at runtime, but it's too late by then. All the functions are generated.

Comment: For example, Arrays are generic over Element. So you need to know Element at compile-time. There's no such thing as `Array<type(of: object)>` (evaluated at runtime). The compiler wouldn't know how big to make it.

Comment: Well that nixed that solution then. I had a feeling it was a bit of a stretch given the Swift is compiled.

Comment: I ended up making the protocol a class so I could pass it around non-generic. It's less extensible, but it works for my use-case. Your answer is the closes to "right" for what I'm doing and has a ton of helpful info so ima mark it solved.